# Visiting every edge only once in a continuous path in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to answer the question of whether it is or is not possible to find a continuous path in a general graph with the following rules:

1. Start and end node for the path are the same.
2. Every edge must be visited, but only once.
3. A node can be visited more than once.
4. Every node has at least 2 connected edges.

A plus would be able to find this path, but at the moment an algorithm which simply says yes or no will suffice.

Comment: Are you ltrying to solve a [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) problem?

Comment: Do you mean: create an algorithm that finds such a path (i.e. Hamiltonian cycle) in an undirected graph?

Comment: A node can be visited more than once.  Not sure if that still makes it a Hamiltonian problem.

Comment: I don't need to find the path.  At this stage I just need to know if there is one or not.

Comment: This appears to be an Eulerian path which exists if and only if every vertex has even degree.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Algorithm that checks if there exists a Hamiltonian cycle in an undirected graph. (without condition 3)*

Here is a Backtracking implementation that checks if there is a Hamiltonian cycle in an undirected graph. The implementation is simple: try to construct a path by the DFS method (Depth-First-Search traversing) and if you don't find a solution backtrack and try to find another neighbor. The solution works to start at node $1$ since it must include all nodes (starting from any other node wouldn't make a difference).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <deque>
#define MAX 15
std::ifstream fin("hamilton.in");
std::ofstream fout("hamilton.out");
using namespace std;
//gasirea unui ciclu hamiltonian intr-un graf neorientat

int n;
bool G[MAX][MAX];

void init_Graph()
{
    fin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            G[i][j] = false;
    int i, j;
    while (fin >> i >> j)
        G[i][j] = G[j][i] = true;
}

void printSolution(int path[])
{
    fout << "1\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        fout << path[i] << " ";
    fout << path[1] << " ";
}

bool isSafe(int v, bool graph[][MAX], int path[], int pos)
{
    if (!graph[path[pos]][v])
        return false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++)
        if (path[i] == v)
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool hamCycleUtil(bool graph[][MAX], int path[], int pos)
{
    if (pos == n) {
        if (graph[path[pos]][path[1]] == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    for (int v = 2; v <= n; v++)
    {
        if (isSafe(v, graph, path, pos)) {
            path[pos+1] = v;
            if (hamCycleUtil(graph, path, pos + 1) == true)
                return true;
            path[pos+1] = -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool hamCycle(bool graph[][MAX])
{
    int* path = new int[n+1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        path[i] = -1;
    path[1] = 1;
    if (hamCycleUtil(graph, path, 1) == false)
    {
        fout << "0\n";
        return false;
    }
    printSolution(path);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    init_Graph();
    hamCycle(G);
    return 0;
}
```

2. *Observation regarding condition 3.*

It is important to note that if condition $3$ is true, then the algorithm transforms in the following problem: **Check if the graph is connected and has an *Eulerian cycle*.** These two problems are equivalent because:

- If a graph isn't connected then there exists at least one vertex $v$ such that you cannot reach $v$, so you cannot create a path with all the nodes;
- If a graph is connected then there exists a path to unite all the nodes. As such a solution would be to simply traverse the graph in one direction, and then by the fact that it is undirected, you can reverse-traverse it and reach the node where you started the search.
- The Eulerian cycle condition comes from condition $2$, by definition.